# Key binding in Julia minor mode

Tags: key-bindings, minor-mode

I am unable to change key binding in a minor mode.

Initiation of minor mode:

```
(add-hook 'julia-mode-hook 'julia-repl-mode)
```

I tried a view variations for the key binding:

```
(add-hook 'julia-repl-mode
    (lambda ()
    (define-key map [C-shift-return] 'julia-repl-send-line)
    (define-key map [C-return] 'julia-repl-send-region-or-line)))
```

or:

```
(eval-after-load 'julia-repl '(define-key julia-repl-map [C-return]
                 'julia-repl-send-region-or-line))
```

But finally without result. I want to bind the command `julia-repl-send-region-or-line` to `C-<eturn>`.
I was at least able to change it interactively with `M-x local-set-key`. But I would like to define it in my init file.
What am I missing?

Comment: Consider saying whether `julia-repl-mode` gets turned on when `julia-mode` is turned on. If so, you can remove the first `add-hook` from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add a hook (solution):

```
(add-hook 'julia-repl-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (define-key julia-repl-mode-map [C-shift-return] 'julia-repl-send-line)
        (define-key julia-repl-mode-map [C-return] 'julia-repl-send-region-or-line)))

(add-hook 'julia-mode-hook 'julia-repl-mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `map` is undefined (aka free) here:

```
(add-hook 'julia-repl-mode
    (lambda ()
      (define-key map [C-shift-return] 'julia-repl-send-line)
      (define-key map [C-return] 'julia-repl-send-region-or-line)))
```

What keymap do you want to bind the keys in?  Is it `julia-mode-map`? `julia-repl-mode-map`? You need to provide an actual keymap as the first argument of `define-key`.

Do you see an error or warning message in buffer `*Messages*` that mentions your unbound variable when your hook function is invoked?  (The error might be ignored.)

(You can put `(debug)` as the first thing inside your lambda, and use `d` in the debugger to see what happens and understand the unbound variable problem, if it's not already clear from what I've said.)

Comment: I also tried both versions: julia-mode-map and julia-repl-mode-map which resulted in the following error: variable void.

Comment: What variable did it say was void - the map variable? Check the julia code, to see what the map variable is called. And be sure that the julia code that defines it actually gets loaded before Emacs tries to evaluate your code that makes use of it.

Comment: Thank you, it worked now. I forgot to add -hook. I will post the solution below.